# Major Differences Between SharePoint 2010 and 2019?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, 2019

I'm planning on migrating to SharePoint 2019, from SharePoint 2010.

There are some posts available regarding the differences between 2016 and 2019, however, I'm wondering if anyone can break down what's new for someone coming from 2010?

What are the major benefits of moving from 2010 to 2019?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a couple of points which I think will help you understand.

- User Interface.

  - in SharePoint 2010, we have **Classic experience** while in SharePoint 2019 it is **Modern experience**. Look and feel is totally change for the **Teams sites** and new introduced **Communication sites**. MySite change to OneDrive, new sync client for it.
- **Modern Pages, Web Parts, Modern Lists, and Libraries** in SharePoint 2019.
- **cloud connectivity**

  - Hybrid connectivity available, with that now we can use Flow and PowerApps in SharePoint 2019. Other Service also be used in Hybrid scenario i.e. UPA, MMS, Search etc
- **OS and SQL Server Support**

  - Latest Windows Server and SQL server version supported with SharePoint 2019, which mean better performance.
- **OneDrive**: Totaly new experience for MySite, which is now one drive and have the latest next-gen sync client.
- Better update process, now fewer products which means an easy process to apply the CU. Zero downtime is a great option.
- The better way to manage the licensing in SharePoint 2019.
- **No SandBox Solution** available in SharePoint 2019 which is in SharePoint 2010.
- A couple of service applications available in SharePoint 2010 which are gone in SharePoint 2019.
- Better limit and boundaries for SharePoint 2019. i.e List view threshold.